# Let $2 = \{ 0, 1 \}$ and $X$, $Y$ be sets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question which I am not sure how to answer.

Let $2 = \{ 0, 1 \}$ and $X$, $Y$ be sets.
Find a bijective function from $2^{X \times Y}$
to $2^{X^Y}$ and Prove that it is a bijection.

Comment: Have you written down what they are, using the definitions?

Comment: @JnxF It not only makes sense, it is the best definition of $2$ known to man. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals).

Comment: @JnxF Actually, it's the way natural numbers are defined set-theoretically. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Comment: @GitGud: I disagree. The best definition of 2 is still "the successor of 1". Of course if you model the natural numbers with the von-Neumann construction, the successor of 1 *turns out to be* $\{0,1\}$. But that's already a result, not the definition.

Comment: @celtschk Well, that's right, but it's such a trivial result that I just called it a definition. But I stand corrected.